# wrong version of gcc being used

Tags: gcc

I've recently been having problems with compiling packages for R. I'm not sure of the causes but one possibility is that there are a couple of different versions of gcc on my MacBook Pro. When I type `which gcc` in a terminal window it returns `/usr/bin/gcc`. But when I type gcc --version I get back

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I may also have some issues with the path. It is currently set to

```
/usr/local/sbin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I added the Applications... path to PATH hoping it would help but it didn't. /usr/bin contains both a g++ and gcc file install May 18, so very recently. I've tried renaming those as a test of whether that would solve the problem but I'm unable to do that even as sudo.

Suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use clang not gcc for macos. If an exam plye says gcc then it probably for Linux

Comment: Since seems you have llvm installed, also brew is installed. With this try ```brew formula R``` and it will show that "gcc" is required for gfortran - so the simplest way to install R is by using ```brew install R``` which will install all required dependences. Brew compiles from sources directly on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

For macOS Clang is a more preferred option (Apple stopped shipping gcc with Xcode and replaced it with Clang and the last version of GCC they supported was 4.2.1, it'll overall be more intuitive.). I'd remove GCC and do the following:

Installation of Clang

1. Run `brew update` and then `brew upgrade` in terminal
2. Run `brew install llvm` to install LLVM and Clang

To put Clang within your PATH variables:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I'm not too sure how different the two are when it comes to compiling (although they are probably very similar.) you can proceed with this [link](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) to catch up on the commands you'll need to use instead.

Comment: Use apple's command line version first

Comment: llvm was already installed. Because of directions from on high I have switched to zsh so the bash profile is probably not being use. At least some of the paths are in /etc/paths so I added the llvm path to it. However, the which gcc command still returns /usr/bin/gcc. How/where is this set?

Comment: Someone downvoted the answer about Clang but didn't say why. Some more explanation would be helpful.